# Using Magento 2 in subdirectory calling nginx.conf.sample

Tags: magento2.4, nginx

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220692/magento-2-in-subfolder-nginx) but I believe magento has changed since then

I am trying to set the location block for calling magento 2.4.6-p3 from a subdirectory with the following
in my nginx 1.24 server configuration:

```
    location ^~ /subdirectory/ {
        set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/example.com/subdirectory;
        include /var/www/example.com/subdirectory/nginx.conf.sample;
    }
```

but when running

```bash
nginx -t
```

I get the following error:

```bash
nginx: [emerg] location "/.user.ini" is outside location "/subdirectory/" in /var/www/example.com/subdirectory/nginx.conf.sample:42
```

which corresponds to this part in the nginx.sample.conf

```
location /.user.ini {
    deny all;
```

what additional info would I need in the server configuration file to avoid this error?

### Update here is the modified config:

```
## Example configuration:
# upstream fastcgi_backend {
#    # use tcp connection
#    # server  127.0.0.1:9000;
#    # or socket
#    server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
# }
# server {
#    listen 80;
#    server_name mage.dev;
#    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
#    set $MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 0;
#    include /vagrant/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
# }
#
## Optional override of deployment mode. We recommend you use the
## command 'bin/magento deploy:mode:set' to switch modes instead.
##
## set $MAGE_MODE default; # or production or developer
##
## If you set MAGE_MODE in server config, you must pass the variable into the
## PHP entry point blocks, which are indicated below. You can pass
## it in using:
##
## fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;
##
## In production mode, you should uncomment the 'expires' directive in the /static/ location block

# Modules can be loaded only at the very beginning of the Nginx config file, please move the line below to the main config file
# load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";


# Deny access to sensitive files
location ~ ^/subdirectory/.user.ini {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location ~ ^/subdirectory/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/subdirectory/pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|custom_options|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location ~ ^/subdirectory/static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version\d*/ {
        rewrite ^/static/version\d*/(.*)$ /static/$1 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json|webmanifest)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location ~ ^/subdirectory/media/ {

## The following section allows to offload image resizing from Magento instance to the Nginx.
## Catalog image URL format should be set accordingly.
## See https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/general/web.html#url-options
#   location ~* ^/media/catalog/.* {
#
#       # Replace placeholders and uncomment the line below to serve product images from public S3
#       # See examples of S3 authentication at https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth
#       # resolver 8.8.8.8;
#       # proxy_pass https://<bucket-name>.<region-name>.amazonaws.com;
#
#       set $width "-";
#       set $height "-";
#       if ($arg_width != '') {
#           set $width $arg_width;
#       }
#       if ($arg_height != '') {
#           set $height $arg_height;
#       }
#       image_filter resize $width $height;
#       image_filter_jpeg_quality 90;
#   }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location ~ ^/subdirectory/media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ ^/subdirectory/media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ ^/subdirectory/media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ ^/subdirectory/media/custom_options/ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ ^/subdirectory/errors/ {
    location ~* \.xml$ {
        deny all;
    }
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.htpasswd$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

which now gives me the following error:

```bash
nginx: [emerg] no port in upstream "fastcgi_backend" in /var/www/example.com/subdirectory/modified_nginx.conf:50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When including Magento's nginx.conf.sample from within a nested location block, some configurations in that sample file will cause conflicts because they're defined with absolute paths.

The error you're seeing is caused by this specific block:

```
location /.user.ini {
    deny all;
}
```

Because this location is absolute, Nginx finds it conflicting with the nested `/subdirectory/` location you defined.

To solve this issue, you'll need to modify the nested location directive and the include directive to work together without conflicts.

Here's what you should do: Instead of including `nginx.conf.sample` directly, create a custom configuration file (`custom_nginx.conf`). Copy everything from `nginx.conf.sample` to `custom_nginx.conf`. Now, make the necessary modifications in `custom_nginx.conf`.

For the specific `/.user.ini` location block, modify it like so:

```
location ~ ^/subdirectory/.user.ini {
    deny all;
}
```

Repeat similar modifications for other absolute path directives in the sample configuration to make sure they're specifically tailored for the `/subdirectory/`.

In your main Nginx server configuration, replace the include directive to point to your new `custom_nginx.conf`:

```
location ^~ /subdirectory/ {
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/example.com/subdirectory;
    include /var/www/example.com/subdirectory/custom_nginx.conf;
}
```

Run `nginx -t` to ensure there are no configuration errors. If there are no errors, reload Nginx to apply the changes.

### Update

The error message you're seeing typically indicates that Nginx doesn't know how to connect to the FastCGI backend because the `fastcgi_backend` upstream is not properly defined in your Nginx configuration (it's commented out). You should uncomment and configure this upstream block so that Nginx knows how to connect to your FastCGI server.

Here's an example of how you can define the `fastcgi_backend` upstream block:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    # use tcp connection
    # server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # or socket
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

Keep this block at the top of your Nginx configuration, just before your server block. Make sure that the server directive in the upstream block matches the configuration of your FastCGI server. In this example, it's using a Unix socket. Adjust it according to your PHP-FPM configuration.

After all, restart Nginx for the changes to take effect. Usually:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: I made all the  changes to the modified config but now I get an error that ``` no port in upstream "fastcgi_backend" in /var/www/example.com/subdirectory/modifed_nginx.conf:50 ```

Comment: @capnhud can you post the error?

Comment: @capnhud please, add whole config ( /var/www/example.com/subdirectory/modifed_nginx.conf:50 ) to your question

Comment: @capnhud I updated my answer